# why division is more accurate than multiplying by its inverse

Tags: c

why X/Y != X*(1/Y)?

why X/Y is more accurate than X*(1/Y)?

In my C coding for matrix inverse I need to do

```
   inv(inp) = [d -b; -c a]*(1/det(inp));
```

I did it in two ways,

case1:

```
temp = 1/det(inp);
 inv(inp) = [d -b; -c a]*temp;
```

case 2:

```
 inv(inp) = [d/det(inp) -b/det(inp); -c/det(inp) a/det(inp)];
```

why case 1 is having error compared to zero error in case 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (Regarding the accuracy question) Because it uses one less operation and floating point operations are usually not exact.

Comment: Where is your actual  code?

Comment: Very abstract/unprecise question, maybe take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic for some basic info. Or clarify your question.

Comment: If when dividing to get Z = 1 / Y you get an error of E then when you multiply Z by X then you effectively multiply the original error E by X, as well as obtaining another potential error.

Comment: "Floating point numbers are like piles of sand; every time you move them around, you lose a little sand and pick up a little dirt."  (Don't remember who said this; I've seen it attributed to Brian Kernighan and P.J. Plauger.)

Comment: Other analogies: A sequence of floating-point operations is sort of like the [game of "telephone"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_(game)): each time you pass the message on, it's likely that an error will be introduced, and errors tend to be lossy, and accumulate.  Or, it's like DNA replication: chromosome ends don't replicate perfectly, so errors accumulate there, and if the errors chew all the way through the protective [telomeres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telomere#Association_with_aging), that's when you can start getting aging effects. (This is an oversimplification, though.)

Comment: 9 ÷ 3 is clearly exactly 3.  But if you say 9 × 1/3, it's likely to be more like 9 × 0.33333, so you're likely to end up with the moral equivalent of 2.99999.

Answer (score 4):

Consider `1/41.f`. In real-number mathematics, dividing 1 by 41 produces the rational number 1/41. This number is not representable in a binary floating-point format. In the format commonly used for `float` (IEEE-754 single precision), the closest we can get to 1/41 is 13094412•2<sup>−29</sup>. So, if `det(inp)` is 41, and you are using `float`, then `temp = 1/det(inp);` sets `temp` to 13094412•2<sup>−29</sup>. The 13094412 part of this is called the *significand*.

Then, if we compute `41*temp`, the result in real-number mathematics would be 536870892•2<sup>−29</sup>. The `float` format only supports a 24-bit significand, so I will rescale this result to bring the significand under 2<sup>24</sup>: 16777215.375•2<sup>−5</sup>. As we can see, the significand is not an integer, so it will not fit in the `float` representation. The nearest representable value is 16777215•2<sup>−5</sup>, which is 0.999999940395355224609375.

Thus, in this case, `41*(1/det(inp))` would give 0.999999940395355224609375, whereas `41/det(inp)` would give 1.

Whenever you perform an operation that gives a floating-point result, the real-number mathematical result is rounded to a representable result. This rounding introduces a small error. Over the course of multiple operations, these errors can compound, cancel, or interact in various ways. By computing the reciprocal of the determinant, you introduce an error that is not present when dividing directly by the determinant.

(The errors can cancel because sometimes the rounding in one operation happens to be in the opposite direction from the rounding in an earlier operation. So sometimes you can get correct results even though the individual operations each had errors.)